# How can i get started on this method?

Tags: java

when one number divides another without leaving a remainder the first number is called a factor of the second.  A number n is said to be perfect if the sum of the factors which are less than n are equal to n.For 
example, 28 is a perfect number because the sum of its factors which are less than 28(1, 2, 4, 7, and 14) equals 28.  Write a boolean method named 
isPerfect that has one integer parameter n, which returns 
true if n is perfect or false if n is not perfect

Comment: Please first try to solve this yourself. If you fail, and have a question, then please show your attempt with your question and try to ask a much more specific question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ["Questions asking for homework help must include a **summary of the work you've done so far** to solve the problem, and a **description of the difficulty you are having** solving it."](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

Everybody would design this differently. I will write my design proposal. I always divide the jobs and implement them as methods. In this task, there are some jobs, which are;

- Get the number (28)
- find its dividers (1,2,4,7,14)
- Check if the total of the dividers is bigger than the number or not
- Do what you want with the result:)

Feel free to ping me if you have any questions.

Comment: (1+) for not spoon-feeding code to the OP who hasn't yet shown his.